# Php header location redirect not working on e-mail signup

Tags: php, redirect

```
 <?php
header("Location:http://www.website.com/");
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0

if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //
  mail( "andrewrichardgale@gmail.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] );

  //            ^
  //  Replace with your email 
}
?>
```

This script is working and saves the e-mail to a .txt but, I would like it to forward to a thank you page as well but, the redirect is not working at all but the signups are.

I don't know PHP i'm using it from a template so I would appreciate any help at all

Comment: where's your redirect code?

Comment: This site is for people who knows programming and needs help, really. (Edit: And honestly, I'm not sure what the first `header()` function is doing up there)

Comment: @Niang the 2nd line I thought where it says header location

Comment: @Max sorry I just don't know where else to turn, the header function was to redirect to another page I thought? I'm just using www.website.com for testing.

Comment: so is there any error  like 404 or just that the page is not working?

Comment: @Niang it doesn't forward anywhere, it just displays the thank you message that was already showing

Comment: and where's the thank you message ? i mean where page it was coded? Im having trouble reading your code, its not complete. sorry.

Comment: i guess you have to post your complete code, and the page you want to redirect

Comment: The thank you message is stored in a h4 class on the html @Niang - The php I posted here is the full PHP file I was given :/

Comment: @Niang 0oo0o00ohhh you're right!!! This is for the contact form, it looks like they're using custom JS to store the e-mails! I just assumed the only php file would be for emails

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
header("Location: YOUR_PAGE");
```

or

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='YOUR_PAGE';</script>";
```

after the mail function has been called.

I really recommend the first one, since it's PHP doing your job, the second one relies in JavaScript, so it's only used when the first is not working.

Comment: Where are you placing the redirects? And what response are you getting?

Comment: Considering that there's an HTTP-redirect at the top of the page, and it doesn't affect him, his client must be ignoring the response-header. As for the answer itself, it's fine and all, but personally I would make a space between `Location:` and `YOUR_PAGE` (not sure if it makes any difference though). Which client ("browser") are you using to browse the page, @CliqFlip?